# How to roll back time of email sent?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

I want to send an email on my computer, but I want the sent day set to 3 days ago.

I don't want to change the date on the receivers end, as I don't believe that's possible, but just on my end.

I went to edit in NotePad++, but it seems the email is encrypted.

I am using Microsoft Exchange, if that's relevant.

Comment: You would have to change the date on the client and the server, even if you do that, it won't change the data of the recipient, who will still only recieve it today.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not worried about the recipient, but rather just on my end. So I need to change my time on my computer, and what else?

Comment: Please read my original comment again.

Comment: @Ramhound and the Microsoft Exchange server? How is that even done?

Comment: It would require me an Administrator on the Exchange Server, and have the authorization, to change the data on the server itself.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without help from your Exchange Administrator. Why do you want to do it anyway? It sound like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know why, but one of my wealthiest clients wants it done for an email. I don't ask questions, that's not my decision to make.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask questions. They are asking you to forge an email. That is potentially fraudulent and illegal (depending on your location and what the email is used for).

Comment: @DavidPostill He's in on another continent and pays well. There's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know the exchange server's address for SMTP access.  Once known, This can be achieved by connecting to the server on port 25 and using the "Date" Permanent Mail Header Field Registration keyword within the **DATA** (Body) of the email when composing.

For example:

> telnet your.exchange.server 25

Send the following once the session is established.

```
EHLO 
MAIL FROM:<from@email.address.com>
RCPT TO:<to@email.address.com>
DATA
Date: Sat, 21 May 2016 05:33:29 -0700
From: Tester <from@email.address.com>
Subject: Dr Who
To: to@email.address.com

I sent this email from the future, but wasn't sure how long it would take for you to receive it.
.
```

Source - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021

Other Source: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference.htm
, good reference incase if anonymous smtp is not permitted as well.